# Codeigniter -> Image Uploading Part 1

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-upload

In my code below it seems that the image does not get uploaded when the folder is created but if I go back and refresh the previous page and try it again with the folder created the image gets uploaded,

Do I have to move the upload stuff into the `is_dir if statement` but what happens in an instance when the folder is already created what goes in the `else?`

```
$conceptOne = 'conceptOne';
        $conceptTwo = 'conceptTwo';

        $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_assets/quote/uploads/';

        $folderName = $this->quote->getCompanyDetails()->companyName;
        $folderName = str_replace(" ", "_", $folderName);
        $folderName = strtolower($folderName);


        if(!is_dir($location.$folderName))
        {   
            mkdir($location.$folderName);
            chmod($location.$folderName, 0777);

        }else{

        //Set File Settings 
          $config['upload_path'] = $location.$folderName; 
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|pdf'; 
          $config['file_name'] = $conceptOne;
          $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
          $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
          $config['max_size'] = '1024'; 
          $config['max_width'] = '1024'; 
          $config['max_height'] = '768'; 

          $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

            print_r($config);

          if(!$this->upload->do_upload($conceptOne)) { #= try upload

            $data['uploadError'] = array('uploadError' => $this->upload->display_errors()); #Error

            $this->load->view('layout', $data);

      } // Do upload
          else{
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data($conceptOne));

          }// end else
        }// end if folde
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the else above

```
//Set File Settings
```

So that the block beneath it is no longer in that condition.